# Android: disable change system settings

Tags: android

We want prevent to change system settings from user. Can we disable right-bottom menu that provide access to the Setting button?

Hardware: 7-ich tablet like Kindle Fire with ICS 4.0

Comment: No.. Not on an unrooted device

Comment: We have rooted devices. And you app will be used only on our devices.